# XQuery pass argument to function

Tags: xml, xquery, element, document

I want to pass a XML Document as an argument to a function called evaluate:

```
declare function my_namespace:evaluate($tree as element()) as element(fraction{
     do something}
```

I tried it with `doc()`, but it returns a *document-node* and I can't cast it to be an *element*. Can somebody tell me how to read an XML file as *element*, so I can pass it to my function?

I tried:

```
for $tree in doc("baum.xml")
let $tree :=$tree treat as element()
return $tree
```

and:

```
let $tree := document("baum.xml")
```

Answer (score 3):

A document node has a single root element as child. You can use a simple child step to pass this root element on to your function:

```
let $tree := doc("baum.xml")/*
return my_namespace:evaluate($tree)
```